# Client to client communication with Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop an Android application which would consist in a forum. I figured I should use the datastore to persist the members. However I was wondering how to implement the sending of posts and private messages to clients?

To be more specific, if A wants to send a message to B, what is the best way to handle this? Must I use Google Cloud Messaging or put A's message to the datastore, and then wait for B to query it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, both solutions are correct.

If you need instant messaging you should choose Google Cloud Messaging to implement this. Device identifier should be stored in the database, when a new message arrives it should be pushed to the specified device using the identifier. You should use notifications on Android side to notify user about new message.

You can also implement this using pull strategy. Message will be saved in the database and queried once user opens your application or clicks refresh button.

The technologies you've used in tags are the correct tools to implement such "forum" thing. Please read the documentation for Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Cloud Messaging because you'll find useful code snippets or even sample applications which will guide you how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation. Would it be a good approach to use the "pull strategy" to post/get the messages and to use GCM only for notifications?

Comment: @Kritias Yes, that's the most suitable design in my opinion.